# Is it feasible to implement anonymous functions in bash (even using eval, if necessary)?

Tags: bash

As bash doesn't have first class functions, I'm simulating anonymous functions by passing a string to a function, which then gets evaluated by `eval`.

```
it() {
    echo "$1" # prints the description of the spec
    beforeEach # a setup function
    eval "$2"

    if (($? == 0)); then
        # do something
    fi

    afterEach  # a cleanup function
}

it "should echo something" '{
  echo "something"
}'
```

This allows to write very concise tests (it defines a specification). Now I wonder if this is a valid use of eval.

**EDIT**

I am aware that the opening { and closing } are not need in the anonymous function string, it's just that that way it resembles for something like Jasmine.

**EDIT**

The `pseudo anonymous function` is actually a test, which means at the end of the test, there is something like

```
[[ var == 'foo' ]]
```

or

```
((i > 10))
```

i.e. some sort of test (or assert, in XUnit terms). It never needs to return anything than the return code which then gets evaluated, and if the return code is 0 (success), the description is printed in green, otherwise red (the test failed).

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I have to vote to close as it's too open to debate.

Comment: The question could be rephrased to be less debatable. For example, *Is it feasible to implement anonymous functions in bash (even using eval, if necessary)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it gets the job done and you (and ideally others) understand how it works, absolutely.

I've been writing similar code for test case automation more than once or twice, but I admit it can get pretty hairy, especially if you start simple and then allow it to grow organically.

For what it's worth, I would like to suggest a stylistic improvement;

```
if eval "$2"; then
  # something
```

or if the "something" is a simple command, plain old

```
eval "$2" && # something
```

Having said that, it might be better if you can avoid the `eval` altogether, but this depends on your test cases.

```
$2 && # something
```

Answer (score 8):

For one-time-use "anonymous" functions, I use the following convention to execute bash scripts in a function scope:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_() {
  #...
} && _ "$@"
unset -f _
```

Although not truly anonymous, this is similar to the [IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) idiom in JavaScript.

Bash functions must have a name.  You can use any name you like (`main` is a popular choice.)  I prefer a single underscore `_` because a) it's short and b) it's conventionally used in many languages to indicate a throwaway value.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is a valid case for eval. Anonymous functions are useful in a few cases: [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) come to mind (alliteration unintended). This implementation gives you none of those powers, since your eval'ed pseudo-functions still can't return a value (other than a 0-255 exit status), and definitely can't return another anonymous function.

Comment: Never apologize for alliteration :)